# Difference between type defined in trait versus type defined in general

Tags: rust

Consider the following code:

```
type ThingIter = dyn Iterator<Item = u64>;

trait Foo {
    type ThingIter: Iterator<Item = u64>;
}

enum Bar<T: Foo> {
    A(T::ThingIter),
    B(ThingIter),
}
```

Compiling this using Rust-1.68.2, the enum arm `A` compiles just fine (i.e., if I comment out `B`, it compiles), but the enum arm `B` does not - I get an error that indicates that `ThingIter` does not have a size that can be known at compile time.

Why is there this difference? The size of `T::ThingIter` also cannot be known at compile time (it could be an iterator to an arbitrarily sized container). Also, short of putting it in a `Box` or taking a reference, what can I do to make the external `type` behave similarly to the internal `type` (i.e., I can put it into an enum without issues)?

Comment: Yes, but generics are monomorphized while trait objects are not.

Comment: And there is nothing you can do to put `dyn Trait` into an enum beside putting it behind some kind of indirection.

Comment: The size of `T::ThingIter` **IS** known at compile time. It has a concrete type known by the compiler in any case. When you `impl Foo for Thing`, you will have to specify what type that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The size of `T::ThingIter` also cannot be known at compile time (it could be an iterator to an arbitrarily sized container).

`T::ThingIter` does have a known size because there's an [implicit `+ Sized` bound](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Sized.html). You have to explicitly opt out of it if you want to also accept unsized types. If you relax that constraint then it also fails to compile:

```
trait Foo {
    type ThingIter: Iterator<Item = u64> + ?Sized;
}
```

Result:

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `<T as Foo>::ThingIter` cannot be known at compilation time
 --> src/lib.rs:8:7
  |
8 |     A(T::ThingIter),
  |       ^^^^^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
```

---

> Also, short of putting it in a `Box` or taking a reference, what can I do to make the external `type` behave similarly to the internal `type` (i.e., I can put it into an `enum` without issues)?

Those are the usual solutions. Enum variants are not allowed to contain dynamically sized fields.

If the iterator is owned elsewhere then a `&` borrow works; otherwise, an owned pointer like `Box`, `Rc`, or `Arc` is sensible.

Comment: I did not realize there was an implicit bound. That makes sense - can you point me to where that is documented so I may read up on it?

Comment: @RK it's documented with the [`Sized`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/marker/trait.Sized.html) trait: "_All type parameters have an implicit bound of `Sized`. The special syntax `?Sized` can be used to remove this bound if it’s not appropriate._"